# Como hacer que un elemento actue como "fixed" hasta cierto punto del scroll y luego se quede en ese punto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Lo que quiero es que el elemento haga scroll hasta cierto punto del scroll porque al llegar al footer este pasa por encima. E conseguido algo con JQuery de cambiar el position a relative a cierta altura del scroll. Esto se complica más cuando quiero que le vuelva el position sticky si el scroll es inferior a lo que yo le pongo.

Código:

```css
/* -------------------------------------NAV & BANNER------------------------ */
#logo{
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
.nav-color{
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.nav-null-color{
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.banner{
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff8000;
}
.title {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
  width: 50vw;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.shadow{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 25%;

}
#large-text{
  font-size: 60px;
}
/* --------------------------------About Us---------------------------------- */
.corporate{
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff8000;
}
.blank{
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
}
/* --------------------------------Worldwide---------------------------------- */
.worldwide{
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 81vw;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff8000;
}
.map{
  border-radius: 15px;
}
/* --------------------------------Careers Title---------------------------------- */
.careers{
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 81vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff8000;
}
/* --------------------------------Contact Us---------------------------------- */
.contact{
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 81vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.btn-lg{
  width: 335px;
}
/* --------------------------------Scroll Menu---------------------------------- */
.scroll-spy{
  /* position: -webkit-sticky; */
  position: sticky;
  top: 2rem;
  height: 10vh;
  border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
/* -------------------------------------------Footer----------------------- */
.footer{
  border-top: 1px solid #ff8000;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60vh;
  background-color: #acb7ba;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#icon{
  font-size: 25px;
}
#youtube{
  height: 200px;
  weight: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Nav Boostrap -->
    <section class="position-absolute">
      <ul class="nav nav-fill fixed-top nav-null-color" id="menu">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white underline" href="#">Corporate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white underline" href="#">Used Machinery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#"> <img src="" id="logo" alt="logo"> </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white underline" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <!-- <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Customer Area</a>
        </li> -->
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white underline" href="#">Sign In/Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    
    
    <!-- About Us -->
    <section id="about" class="corporate text-center">
      <div class="screen-center">
        <h1 class="text-dark">About us</h1>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6 blank">
            <h3>gsfgdfgdfgdg</h3>
            <p>fsdfgsdgdsfgsdfgsdfg</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 scroll-spy" id="">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column ml-5 mt-5 spy-menu">
          <h4>Corporate</h4>
          <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#top"> About Us</a>
          <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#worldwide">Worldwide</a>
          <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#careers">Careers Title</a>
          <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="prueba" value="">
        <input type="text" id="prueba2" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <!-- Worlwide -->
        <section id="worldwide" class="worldwide text-center">
          <h1 class="mt-5 mb-5">Worldwide</h1>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
              <div class="col ml-5">
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item active">dfgdfgdfgdfg</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">dfgdfgdfg</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">dfdfdgd</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">dfgdf</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">e-mail: jdfgdfgdfg</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Tel :dfgdfgdg‹</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item active">dfgdfgd</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Cdfgdfg</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">2dfgdfgn</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">dfgdfga</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">SdfgdfgN</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">e-mail: dfgdfgdfg</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">dfgdgdfg</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item active">OdfgdfgK</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">fgdfgdg
                  <li class="list-group-item">email: gffhfgfgh</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Tel: +fhghfg9</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item active">Ogfghfhhu </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">udrgdrgdg vhghdgfdrdr</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">rdgrgg</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">email: rdgdrgds</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Tel.: drgdgrgdrg</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Careers Title -->
        <section id="careers" class="careers">
          <div class="screen-center">
            <h1 class="text-dark">Careers Title</h1>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-6 blank">
                <p>drgdrgdrgdrgdrgdg</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Contact Us -->
        <section id="contact" class="contact">
          <div class="screen-center">
            <h1 class="text-dark">Contact Us</h1>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row justify-content-center blank">
                <div class="col-4">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>Albania</option>
                        <option>Angola</option>
                        <option>Argelia</option>
                        <option>Argentina</option>
                        <option>Armenia</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile">
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <textarea class="form-control mt-3" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg">Send</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>    
    
    <!-- Footer -->
    <section class="footer">
      <div class="container mt-3 mb-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <span><i class="fa fa-building" id="icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4 class="ml-3">Company</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">About Us</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">Offices</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">News Media</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <span><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4 class="ml-3">drgdrgdy</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">drgdgdgy</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">Ordgdgrdrgr</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">rdgdrgdg</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <span><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4 class="ml-3">Contact</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                  <option>Worldwide Contact</option>
                </select>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <span><i class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4 class="ml-3">Legal</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">Legal Information</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">COOKIES Policy</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <span><i class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4 class="ml-3">ggggg</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">rgdgdrg</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">fthgdrgd</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <span><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4 class="ml-3">Language</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                  <option>English</option>
                  <option>Spanish</option>
                  <option>German</option>
                  <option>Italian</option>
                  <option>Russian</option>
                </select>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <span><i class="fa fa-building" id="icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <h4 class="ml-3">Account</h4>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">drgdgdrgd</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">drgdg</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">drgdrgdgdg</a>
                <a class="nav-link text-dark underline" href="#">drgdgdrgdrgs</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="img/youtube.png" id="youtube" alt="youtube">
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($("#menu").offset().top > 56) {
            $("#menu").addClass("nav-color");
        } else {
            $("#menu").removeClass("nav-color");
        }
        $('#prueba').val(window.scrollY);
        if ($('.scroll-spy').offset().top > 2500) {
          $('#prueba2').val(1);
          $('.scroll-spy').css('position', 'relative');
          $('.scroll-spy').css('top', '1800px');
        } else {
          $('#prueba2').val(2);
          $('.scroll-spy').css('position', 'sticky');
          $('.scroll-spy').css('top', '2rem');
        }
      });
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Para verlo merjor abrirlo en pantalla completa el ejemplo.

Comment: Con una media query, y le indicas que despues de cierto punto se vuelva static
no recuerdo muy bien todo el proceso pero la sintaxis es asi `@media (los pixeles minimos o maximos)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece ser que mi problema era que estaba haciendo offset().top the la clase ".scroll-spy" y cuando pasaba los 2500px le aplicaba un top de 1800px lo que causaba que el offset().top de ".scroll-spy" fuese siempre 1800px una vez pasados los 2500px que le puse como límite. La solución es usar "windows.scrollY" en su lugar. El código JQuery quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("#menu").offset().top > 56) {
        $("#menu").addClass("nav-color");
    } else {
        $("#menu").removeClass("nav-color");
    }
    $('#prueba').val(window.scrollY);
    if (window.scrollY > 2500) {
      $('#prueba2').val(1);
      $('.scroll-spy').css('position', 'relative');
      $('.scroll-spy').css('top', '1800px');
    } else {
      $('#prueba2').val(2);
      $('.scroll-spy').css('position', 'sticky');
      $('.scroll-spy').css('top', '2rem');
    }
  });

</script>
```